# Creating a installer which will run a specific batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, x509certificate, digital-certificate, setup.exe

I need a help from you. Here is my total scenario:

I have created a batch file which will install some digital certificate. Now I need to make a one click installer(.exe) which will extract all the files (my provided digital certificates and bat file in the .exe file) to the temp folder and run the bat file to install them. After finishing, it delete the extracted files from temp folder. I made the bat file and it is working well but can't make the one click installer.

Can anyone suggest me how to create that one click installer (.exe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows comes with an integrated installer creator. IExpress.

Comment: IExpress is not working. I tried it to create a exe file. But it didn't work. When I run bat file it works fine but when i try to run bat file through exe file, it misses file path. Why this is happening?

Comment: @S.R.KAkash: "misses file path"? When you create a installer with IExpress, the batch file is inside the generated exe. When the exe file is executed, all its contents are decompressed in a temp folder and the command indicated is executed. In your case, the command should be something like `cmd.exe /c myBatchFile.cmd`. Without any path. It will be executed inside the temporary generated folder. From batch file, the current directory is `%cd%`, the full path to batch file is `%~f0` and the directory where the batch file is located is `%~dp0`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer 7z for mine.  See link in MikeG's comment for additional details.

https://superuser.com/questions/42788/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-file-after-extraction-from-a-7-zip-self-extracting-a